# xcode / swift receiving user data through a form

Tags: swift, firebase

I've been designing an app where the user needs to be able to send me the value of certain variables within the app. I originally planned to use a simple mail setup where they fill out a form and the game data is automatically filled out in the email. 
Is there any way a user can click a button, and send me the values of variables within the app without the user specifically seeing or being able to modify the variables?
The user consents and realizes what they are doing to. I've been looking at firebase and seeing if there's anything there which can help me. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way a user can click a button, and send me the values of
>   variables within the app without the user specifically seeing or being
>   able to modify the variables?

Yes. Add a `UIButton` to your storyboard and create a `IBAction` for it. Whenever the button gets tapped the `IBAction` gets called. In this case the `IBAction` is named `didTapbutton`. See the code below:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var secretName = "Bond"
    var secretNumber = 007

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func didTapButton(_ sender: Any) {
        mail(to: secretName, secretNumber: secretNumber)
    }

    func mail(to secretName: String, secretNumber: Int) {
        print("hello \(secretName + secretNumber)")
    }
}
```

`didTapButton` uses the local variables `secretName` and `secretNumber` "within the app" without the user seeing the values.

Comment: Thanks for the swift response ( no pun intended ), I’ll give this a go soon. So does this actually work as a functional way for a user to send an email to my personal account without them understanding the hidden contents or the secret recipient? Sorry if this is a dumb question.

Comment: @callumschenk this code doesn't send an email, it's only printing the "secret variables" on the console. I'm pretty sure it's not possible to use secret data and have it emailed to you without the users knowing - since the email app will open with the content visible and the recipient.